# Automatic folding based on bol

Tags: folding

How might Ι automatically fold all paragraphs where every line begins with `%%`? Would be good for comments in TeX.

Answer (score 2):

Try this setting:

```
 :set foldenable foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\s*%%'
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems, though, that with this setting, it is no longer possible to create folds without this pattern with `:fold`.